# Basic Statistics Question , just need to check answer.

Tags: statistics

Find the Median if Mode is 66 for the following distribution:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 \text{Class Interval} & \text{Frequency} \\
\hline
30-40 & 8 \\                    
40-50 & 16 \\                  
50-60 & 22 \\                   
60-70 & 28 \\                  
70-80 & ?  \\                 
80-90 & 12 \\
\end{array}
$$

Now I get the missing frequency as 24 taking modal class as 60-70 (basic knowledge of statistics) and solving.And I get the median as 63.21728 taking cumulative frequencies and applying formula.

But the book says the answer is 62.32. I tried getting frequency using this median but the mode did not match for that frequency. I am pretty sure this answer is wrong but still think I must have committed a mistake.

If someone has the patience to check the answer and point my mistake if any,then that would be aprreciated

Comment: I also get 63.21... and when we try and add a bit of a curve to the ogive this will only increase the answer.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Thanks for that, the book must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: How do you get $24$ rather than perhaps "something between $12$ and $28$" for the missing frequency?

Comment: @henry I use the simple mode formula and solve for the missing frequency as a variable.Wait, is that a hint or are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking.  The mode is simply the most likely value, as opposed to the middle (median) or average (mean) values.   What is your "mode formula"?

Comment: @Henry The mathjax seems complicated now but this one(as I said basic stats knowledge): [link] (https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mode+formula+for+grouped+data&espv=2&biw=1024&bih=667&site=webhp&tbm=isch&imgil=gCa6wPQ1HD3T7M%253A%253B10JmFM2GSLg1aM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fmba-lectures.com%25252Fstatistics%25252Fdescriptive-statistics%25252F146%25252Fmode.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=gCa6wPQ1HD3T7M%253A%252C10JmFM2GSLg1aM%252C_&usg=__01hyshGhTR2NkdB1P5Gf204IAgw%3D#imgrc=gCa6wPQ1HD3T7M%3A)

Comment: OK - I see the formula for a estimate of the mode from the frequency of its class interval and the class intervals immediately above and below.  Doing the process in reverse looks more difficult to justify: it is like regressing $y$ against $x$ and then predicting a missing $x$ value from a given $y$ value.

Comment: For example, you seem to not be using the fact that $12 \lt 16$, so perhaps the book thinks the upper tail falls away faster than the lower tail.  What would happen if you set $? = \frac{28+12}{2} = 20$ for the $70-80$ class interval frequency?

Comment: @henry Sorry about that, some of that went above my head. Anyways this is question in my Quantitative Aptitude portion for the test I am preparing and there are four answers, you know multiple choice therefore steps not required, that is why I was checking the answer cause I just wanted to know whether the answer was wrong.